# How to duplicate row in SQL Query result

Tags: ms-access

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
```

```
ID      Name 
1       SOF
2       USER
```

I want query which can one or two or four ....  times ID = 1 in row like

What will be the Query of this in Ms.Access?

```
ID      Name 
1       SOF
1       SOF
1       SOF
2       USER
```

Comment: If you can explain the logic behind the requirement, perhaps a solution will be easier to come up with.

Comment: It is also easy to duplicate rows on the client-side.

Comment: SELECT Badges.*, BadgeTypes.*, Countries.* FROM (Badges INNER JOIN BadgeTypes ON Badges.TypeID = BadgeTypes.TypeID) INNER JOIN Countries ON Badges.CountryID = Countries.CountryID order By PName

Comment: i want some badges to get print duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Following example uses SQL Server's CTE syntax.

As it stands, the `@ID` gets selected `@Count` times, all other records are selected one time. It would be fairly easy to extend it to whatever count for whatever ID's you like.

**Setup**

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INTEGER, Name VARCHAR(32))
DECLARE @Count INTEGER
DECLARE @ID INTEGER

SET @Count = 3
SET @ID = 1

INSERT    INTO @Table 
          SELECT 1, 'SOF'
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'USER'
```

**SQL Statement**

```
;WITH Multiple AS (
  SELECT  ID, Name, cnt = 1
  FROM    @Table
  WHERE   ID = @ID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  ID, Name, cnt = cnt + 1
  FROM    multiple
  WHERE   cnt < @Count
)
SELECT  ID, Name
FROM    Multiple
UNION ALL
SELECT  ID, Name
FROM    @Table
WHERE   ID <> @ID
```

Comment: How can I. You've only just added that tag?!

Comment: I m sorry i forgot lieven i have added ms-access tag now

Comment: Don't worry about it but I have no idea how to do it using Access besides making it a Pass Through query (to SQL Server :).

Answer (score 0):

This solution depends on having a LabelCount field (column) with the required number of labels, and a Coiunter table, with a field, Num, that contains integers from 1 to maximum number of labels required:

```
SELECT Id, [Name]
FROM Table1, [Counter]
WHERE Counter.Num<=[LabelCount]
```

Answer (score 0):

In an Access report it can be done without changing the SQL. This really ancient Knowledge Base article explains it, and I've had it in production use for nearly 15 years!

[How to Skip Used Mailing Labels and Print Duplicates](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;95806)